# How do I use the Three.js FBXLoader properly?

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, brackets, fbx

I'm trying to use the Three.js FBXLoader and I'm fairly new to it. 
When I tried loading the FBX model I exported from blender though it didn't work. Were no errors in the console and It's a little frustrating.

I have tried :

- Inflate.min.js
- moving the camera
- Changing the way I export in blender
- Using OnError. (but I could be using it wrong.)
- Etc

Here's my Javascript Code for the loader:

```
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
loader.load('mmm.fbx', function (object) { scene.add(object) });
```

It was basic so I expected my model to load properly but nothing's happening. Everything else is working properly but the model isn't.

Comment: I am assuming you already have a renderer object running, is that right?

Comment: I have experienced problems like this one when I do not add an actor (Or animation), so I have to add an empty animation with a single keyframe.

Comment: Yes I have the render object running, and sorry for asking I'm new but how do I do that?

Comment: Hi, I just added a cube to the scene to make sure there wasn't something wrong with my localhost. When I zoomed out I found my model ; it just black. Whenever I zoomed out too far though it would just disappear. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: @Kenny Did you add a light? You can try 'object.frustumCulled = false' to try to solve disappearing problem. It would be much easier to solve with a jsfiddle.

Comment: Check out this example that uses the FBX loader: https://boxelizer.com/renderer.php?mid=60e08f7b67d34fd3881659e7d58b38f7

Comment: I haven't added lights yet but I did notice something odd. Everytime I moved back with orbit controls I would alway see my model but no matter which direction I moved in I would always run into it. For some odd reason I can only see it up close and I can't change it's position ; later I checked the three.js editor and I'm having the same issue there too.

Comment: I tried using object.frustumCulled = false, it didn't change so I think it might be an export or import problem, I also added in a light and my model is affected by the light but It isn't visible when I zoom back in.